# Alamofire post request doesn't work?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using alamofire latest version(swift 3), my pod installation like below,

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'master'
```

And I'm trying to send a request as below, it worked for alamofire previous versions. However it doesn't work with this version.

In my opinion, the parameters are not sent properly.

```
 let param: Parameters = ["grant_type": "password",
                 "username": "0767898037",
                 "password" : "Hammer@123"]
    NSLog("param \(param))")
    Alamofire.request("http://api.xxxx.com/token" , method: .post, parameters: param , encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        NSLog("res \(response.request))")
        switch response .result {

        case .success(let JSON) :
            NSLog("values \(response.result.value))")
            let response2 = JSON as! NSDictionary
             NSLog("values22 \(response2.value(forKeyPath: "access_token")))")
        case .failure(let error) :
            NSLog("errr \(response.result.value))")
            NSLog("error \(error))")
            let error = error as Error
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error in the console as follows:

```
2017-03-21 18:21:42.572362 com.sodesync.dudget.iOSClient[5927:1259497] values Optional({
error = "unsupported_grant_type";
}))
```

Comment: Doesn't `{ error = "unsupported_grant_type"; }` comes from your api server?

Comment: yes but api is working properly. i tested on Postman

Comment: Please share your Postman request

Comment: And, btw, why are you using cutting-edge/last-commit version of `Alamofire` instead of latest stable release?

Comment: im using this:  pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'master'

Comment: @AnushkaMadushan, yes, but why? Why not just `pod 'Alamofire'` to get latest **stable** version instead of what's current in `master`?

Comment: yes now i added but same result

Comment: in my info.plist i allow permissions like this:<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict> is this fine?

Answer (score 1):

Your server tells you that the grant type you provide (password) is not OK.

I would suggest testing your request via `RESTed` or `Postman` or `curl`.

Comment: but i tested in postman it is working properly for same request and the parameters

Comment: Are you entirely sure? Maybe a Header-Field is different, such as "Content-Type"?

Comment: yes. see this is the bulk edit from postman grant_type:password
username:0767898037
password:Hammer@123

Comment: in my info.plist i allow permissions like this:<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict> is this fine?